# An ordinal $\nu$ is a natural iff there is no injection $f$ of $\nu$ into $X$ in $\mathscr P(\nu)\setminus\{\nu\}$.

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, examples-counterexamples, ordinals, natural-numbers

Let's we prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem**
>
> An ordinal $\nu$ is a natural if and only if there is no injection of $\nu$ into $X$ in $\mathscr P(\nu)\setminus\{\nu\}$.
>
> *Proof*.
>
> Let's we assume there no exists an injection $f$ of $\nu$ over any $X$ in $\mathscr P(\nu)\setminus\{\nu\}$. So if $\nu$ was not a natural the there would be exists $A$ in $\mathscr P(\nu)$ with no maximum element so that let be $\alpha$ the corresponding initial ordinal: this ordinal exists independently by **AC** since $A$ is a set of ordinals so that it is well ordered!
> Now if $\alpha$ was in $\nu$ then by transitivity the inclusion
> $$
> \alpha\subseteq\nu
> $$
> would hold and thus by the above hypothesis it must be an equality: we conclude in this way that the inequality
> $$
> \nu\le\alpha\tag{1}\label{1}
> $$
> holds. So by ineq. \eqref{1} we observe that the inequality
> $$
> |\nu|\le|\alpha|=\alpha
> $$
> holds but by the inclusion
> $$
> A\subseteq\nu
> $$
> also the inequality
> $$
> \alpha=|A|\le|\nu|
> $$
> holds so that we argue the equality
> $$
> \alpha=|\nu|
> $$
> holds: thus if $\alpha$ is initial then by ineq. \eqref{1} we conclude the equality
> $$
> \alpha=\nu\tag{2}\label{2}
> $$
> Now by hypothesis $A$ has not maximum element so that if it is equipotent to $\alpha$ then by eq. \eqref{2} we argue that $\nu$ has not maximum element so that it is a limit ordinal and thus surely the inequality
> $$
> \omega\le\nu
> $$
> holds since we supposed $\nu$ is not a natural so that it is not empty. Now the function
> $$
> f:=\big\{(n,m)\in\omega\times\omega:m=n+1\big\}
> $$
> is a bjection over $\omega_+$ so that the function
> $$
> g:=\big\{(\delta,\lambda)\in\nu\times\nu:\lambda=f(\delta)\text{ if $\delta\in\omega$},\lambda=\delta\text{ otherwise}\big\}
> $$
> is an bjection of $\nu$ onto $\nu\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and this is impossible by original hypothesis: so we conclude that $\nu$ is an natural.
>
> Finally if $\nu$ is a natural number then by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSYzq.png) lemma we conclude that there is no injection of $\nu$ over $X$ in $\mathscr P(\nu)\setminus\{\nu\}$.

So first of all I ask if the above theorem holds (I elaborate it by myself!) and so if I well proved it; moreover, I would like to know if it is possibile the implication I did not prove directly whithout induction -or recursion: could someone help me, please?

Comment: Lack of injection from $X$ to any of its proper subsets is literally the definition of being finite. Or rather Dedekind finite. Are you trying to show here that an ordinal is Dedekind finite iff it is finite?

Comment: @freakish The proof is divided into the following four steps:
1. Let's we assume there exist an injection of $\nu$ into $A\in\mathscr P(\nu)$ so that $A$ is well ordered and thus let be $\alpha$ the corresponding initial ordinal;
2. By transitivity of ordinals and by definition of initial ordinal we argue the equality $\alpha=\nu$;
3. by the equality $\alpha=\nu$ we argue the inequality $\omega\le\nu$ since $\nu$ is not empty;
4. we make a bjection of $\nu$ onto $\nu\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and thus the theorem follow by reductio ad absurdum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For natural numbers, you can get an essentially identical proof to the one by induction by saying 'let $n$ be the least natural number such that $n$ has an injection onto a proper subset of itself.  Then use the same argument as in the linked proof to show that $n-1$ has one'.

You can get a different proof if using a different equivalent definition of finiteness.  For example, the complementary version of Tarski-finiteness.  A set $X$ is finite if and only if every non-empty
$Y\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ has a $\subseteq$-minimal element.

Assume $X$ is Tarski-finite and $f\colon X\to X$ is injective onto a proper subset of $X$.  Let
$$
Y=\{A\subseteq X\colon f(A)\subsetneq A\}
$$
Then $Y$ is nonempty because $X\in Y$.  Let $A_0$ be a $\subseteq$-minimal element of $Y$.  Then $f(A_0)\subsetneq A_0$.  Let $t\in A_0\setminus f(A_0)$.  Let $B=A_0\setminus \{t\}$.

Since $t\not\in f(A_0)$ then $f(A_0)\subseteq B$.  Therefore $f(B)\subseteq B$.  Let $u=f(t)$.  Then $u\in B$, and since $f$ is injective, there is no $s\in B$ such that $f(s)=u$.  This shows that $f(B)\subsetneq B$.  But then $B\in Y$, contradicting the $\subseteq$-minimality of $A_0$.

Your proof for infinite ordinals is fine.  You can summarize to say there is a class function $F$ defined on all ordinals by $F(n)=n+1$ for $n<\omega$ and $F(\alpha)=\alpha$ for $\alpha\ge\omega$.  Then for all $\alpha\ge\omega$, $F\rvert_\alpha$ is an injective function from $\alpha$ onto a proper subset of $\alpha$.

Edit: If $X$ is a finite set with $|X|=n$, the argument above shows that
$$
X\supsetneq f(X)\supsetneq f^2(X)\supsetneq f^3(X)\supsetneq\ldots
$$
Since $X$ has $n$ elements and each step deletes at least one element, after at most $n$ iterations we get the empty set and that leads to a contradiction since $\emptyset\supsetneq f(\emptyset)$ is impossible.

This is also a proof by induction, but hopefully makes it more transparent what's going on.  Since each application of $f$ contracts $X$, starting with a finite set, eventually the process drains $X$.  If $X$ is (Dedekind) infinite it's possible to repeat such a process indefinitely many (finite) number of steps and still remain with a set which is 'as large' as the original.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I do not see why if $X$ is finite then it is Tarski-finite: could you prove it, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: That's done by induction.  There's no way to avoid induction in proving things about the natural numbers.  It's like asking to prove something about them without using their properties.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro:  You can prove this by saying if $X$ has $n$ elements, then all subsets of $X$ are finite, then take one of smallest size - it has to also be minimal.  But then 'taking one of smallest size' is also induction.  And proving that a subset of a finite set is finite is done by induction.

Comment: I am reflecting about: give me some minutes to elaborate your comments.

Comment: I reflected and I concluded what to follow: if $\lambda$ is not natural then the inequality $\omega\le\lambda$ holds so that if you find $Y\subseteq\mathcal P(\omega)$ without $\subseteq$-minimal then the statement follows, right? Do you know a such $Y$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: $Y=\{\omega,\omega\setminus 1,\omega\setminus 2,\omega\setminus 3,\ldots\}$.  It's a descending family with empty intersection so no member can be $\subseteq$-minimal.

Comment: Nice! Intuitively I see that $Y$ has not a $\subseteq$-minimal element but I am not able to prove it immediately: are you able to do this?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro:  The natural numbers are characterized by three Peano axioms.  1) $+1$ is injective.  2) $n+1\ne 0$ for all $n$ and 3) Induction.  It is impossible to prove statements about natural numbers that follow from $1+2+3$ but are independent from $1+2$ without induction.  When you have to use induction, may as well use the most economical way.

Comment: Help me: if $m$ and $n$ in $\omega$ are distinct then without loss of generality we can suppose $m\subseteq n$ so that $\omega\setminus n\subseteq\omega\setminus m$ and so $Y$ is a chain, right? Now if $Y$ has a $\subseteq$-minimal element then it would be a minimum...

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: $\omega\setminus m\not\subseteq\omega\setminus (m+1)$.

Comment: Eureka! If $y$ was a minimum for $Y$ then there would be exists $n$ in $\omega$ such that $\omega\setminus n\subseteq\omega\setminus m$ for any $m$ in $\omega$ so that the inclusion $m\subseteq n$ holds and thus even the inequality $m\le n$ which is impossibile: indeed in this case $n$ would be the maximum of $\omega$ but this is impossibile since $\omega$ is limit. What do you think about? P.S. I did not understand what you want mean with your last comment.

Comment: Uhm... if prove that if $\lambda$ is infinite ordinal then it is not Tarski-finite then we by contraposition we only can argue that if $\nu$ is a Tarski-finite ordinal then it is finite but I prove just this above: however this it seems is a more simple proof!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro:  See Edit.

Comment: Well, actually it seems that induction or recursion are necessarily, sob! However, the most important think is to be aware about truth of the theorem of which you suggested an alternative proof into the answer and into the comment: so I upvoted and approved your answer. So I thank you to endure my petulance: thanks really for the assistance!!! :-)